# HTML select: how to set drop down text

Tags: javascript, html, select, drop-down-menu, readfile

How do I set the text values of a HTML drop down list to a value/variable from a external text or .js file. ( The value that will be displayed in the drop down list )

for example:

```
 <select id="usernameDropDown">
 <option value="username1">name1</option>
 <option value="username2">name2</option>
 <option value="username3">name3</option>
 </select>
```

I'm trying to dynamically change the values as above "name1" and "name2" and so on to the values from a local .js file. 
Currently I have the values from the .js files written on the html page successfully with the following code segment:

```
<script src="jstest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script Language='JavaScript'>
document.write(name1)
document.write(name2)
document.write(name3)

document.write(CSRUsername1)
document.write(CSRUsername2)
document.write(CSRUsername3)
</script>
```

currently the .js file is setup something like this:

```
var name1="Alpha" 
var name2="Bravo"
var name3="Charlie"
var name4="Delta"
var name5="Echo"
```

Is there any method to set this text value using values from a text file or .js file?
If possible, I would like to keep the solution in html / java script only..

Comment: Maybe use something like Knockout.js?

Comment: What causes the select value to change?

Comment: @ Mike, looks like that would work unfortunately this needs to work on systems where I have to use already installed libraries...

@ Mark, Nah can't use Jquery as above ^.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to load a drop down dynamically [[Fiddle]](http://jsfiddle.net/yYW89/961/).

HTML

```
<select id="usernameDropDown">
    <option>Choose a user</option>
</select>
```

Javascript

```
    var select = document.getElementById("usernameDropDown");
    var unames = ["Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie", "Delta", "Echo"];
    for (var i = 0; i < unames.length; i++) {
        var opt = unames[i];
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.textContent = opt;
        el.value = opt;
        select.appendChild(el);
    }
```

Comment: You've solved my problem and also solved the next step i was looking to take -- setting the value of each.

Comment: Fiddle also made it very clear.
Only reason I'm choosing this one - its slightly cleaner. A couple of great answers thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

You can try setting the `innerText` property of each of the `option` elements:

```
var s = document.getElementById('names');
s.children[0].innerText = name1;
s.children[1].innerText = name2;
s.children[2].innerText = name3;
```

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k3c2k/).

Note that here you would need to know which child is where (e.g. the first child of the `select` is `name1`, etc.).

An alternative way to pick the children is to set ID attributes for each option, and use `document.selectElementById` on each `option` element.

Comment: great! exactly what I needed. I regret testing so many different approaches on this, thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

Creates the options from scratch and adds them to the drop down list. The label is the text and the value is the value.

```
var dropdown = document.getElementById('usernameDropDown');

// if dropdown exists
if(dropdown) {
    var usernames = [
        { label: 'name1', value: 'username1' },
        { label: 'name2', value: 'username2' },
        { label: 'name3', value: 'username3' }
    ];

    for(var i=0,l=usernames.length; i<l; i++) {
        var username = usernames[i];

        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.setAttribute('value',username.value);

        var optionText = document.createTextNode(username.label);
        option.appendChild(optionText);

        dropdown.appendChild(option);
    }
}
```

Comment: This will certainly help If I have an unknown number of names/usernames to add as options. x.appendChild is another method for what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, and this circumvents a potential problem with the method selected as the answer: if you have less options in the HTML than the Javascript expects, you hit an out-of-bounds error.

Comment: @DissidentRage +1 for good answer, my thought was that if you ought to know how many `option` elements there are if you know how many variables to set.

Answer (score 1):

My idea:

HTML:

```
<select id="usernameDropDown">
 <option value="username1">name1</option>
 <option value="username2">name2</option>
 <option value="username3">name3</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
window.onload = init;

var names=["Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie", "Delta", "Echo"];

function init(){
    var opts = document.getElementById("usernameDropDown").childNodes;

    for (var i=0, i<opts.length, i++){
        opts[i].innerHTML = names[i];
    }
}
```

The javascript sets the 'innerHTML' property to the name string taken from the array. Not as elegant as Dissident Rage's version but shorter :D

Answer (score 1):

Here is a really quick jQuery method that you could use

UPDATED version:
It updates your select dynamically from your array
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j4AWe/)

Your HTML

```
<select id="usernameDropDown">
 <option value="username1">Username</option>
</select>
```

Your javascript

```
var name = ["Alpha","Bravo","Charlie","Delta","Echo"];

for(i=0;i<name.length;i++){
    $("#usernameDropDown").append("<option value='name" + i + "'>" + name[i] + "</option>");
}
```

Comment: This code also requires that the option be pre-designated in the HTML, notice how in the fiddle the option list only gets populated to, "Charlie".

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#usernameDropDown option").each(function(){
   if($(this).html() == "name1")
   {
     $(this).html(name1)
   } 
   if($(this).html() == "name2")
   {
     $(this).html(name2)
   } 
   if($(this).html() == "name3")
   {
     $(this).html(name3)
   } 
});
```